# Сделать стрелки для прокрутки слайдера

Tags: html, css, слайдер

Нужно сделать стрелочки, для прокрутки слайдера вправо `>` `<` влево и чтобы при нажатии отображался следующий слайд. Как это возможно реализовать, желательно на `css` ну или на `js` если выбора нету? Вот код:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider input[name="switch"] {
  display: none;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.switch label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #2f363c;
  background-color: #738290;
}

#btn1:checked~.switch label[for="btn1"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn2:checked~.switch label[for="btn2"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn3:checked~.switch label[for="btn3"] {
  background-color: white;
}

.slider-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 300%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.slides img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#btn1:checked~slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(0);
}

#btn2:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-1000px);
}

#btn3:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-2000px);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn2">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn3"> 

  <div class="switch">
    <label for="btn1"></label>
    <label for="btn2"></label>
    <label for="btn3"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="img/test2.png">
      <img src="img/test2.png">
      <img src="img/test3.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Без `js` тут не обойтись. Используйте лучше готовый слайдер. Не усложняйте жизнь себе и тем, кто будет в дальнейшем работать с вашим кодом.

Comment: На CSS можно, но это километровый вынос мозга с чекбоксами или радио-кнопками. Поэтому легче JS)